# `chrome.tabs.executeScript` after window.location change

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to execute list of codes in a chrome tab. In my extension I have a socket connection with a node server which provide functions (as string). Background script is listening to socket messages and executing those functions. I can execute using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` API.

```
/*
This will be executed on socket message
I'm using babel to generate ES5 code. ES6 code as below
Ex: receivedFunc = "(function () {console.log("print something")})()"
*/
await Tabs.execute(tabInfo.id, {
    code: receivedFunc,
    runAt: "document_idle"
});
```

But due to these scripts (button click or form submit or manual window.location change), `window.location` will be changed. I want execution to be paused until window location change completed. I can listen to `chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addEventListener()` to get the status of a specific tab (callback function receives tabNumber and it's status, whether it's loading or completed loading).

So what I'm looking for is something like below or better approach.

```
socket.on('message', (data) => {
    let receivedFunc = data.func;

    if(loading(tabNumber)){
        waitUntilComplete();

    await Tabs.execute(tabInfo.id, {
        code: receivedFunc,
        runAt: "document_idle"
    });
});
```

How can I pause the execution? Is there a better approach?

Comment: _I want execution to be paused until window location change completed._ Execution of what? Injected scripts? AFAIU they are already executed, otherwise `window.location` wouldn't change. And do you realize that such approach will lead to infinite loop (injected script causes `window.location` change, which causes injected script execution again ans so on)?

Comment: Check tab.status == 'loading' and if so, await for tabs.onUpdated listener that checks tab.status. Just don't forget to detach the listener.

Comment: @hindmost there is no infinite loops. because executeScript inject it to current page.

Comment: `tabs.get()` to get the `status`. If `"loading"` add to a global Object you have (e.g. called `onTabComplete`) to which you add a reference to a callback for execution when `tabs.onUpdated` indicates a tab's `status` changes to `"complete"`.

Comment: `WebNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` , ` tabs.onUpdated` and `tabs.get(123).status` doesn't change the status immediately. There is a little time gap between "after running window.location='https://google.com' " and getting the status callback, that is the status is `complete`.  Any idea how to get the `beforeunload` event to `chrome extension`?